# Azure App Insights: How limits log informations for a specif domain or ipaddress

Tags: azure, appinsights

Is there a way to configure Azure App Insight to collect logs informations only from a single ipaddress or a single domain?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with App Insights.

To achieve this, you can deploy your website multiple times with different configurations (AppInsights logging enabled / disabled) for the different hostnames / IPs.

You did not tell the reason why not all data for different hostnames should not be logged. I guess this is related to security reasons.

If this is no hard requirement, you just filter the AppInsights results for specific hostnames or IPs.